# change backgroundcolor on textArea from external CSS

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Im trying to change the background color on my textarea from an external css.
I can change the color of the buttons so the style sheet is working. But I cant seem to ad the class into the text area.

I can call the class on my button with `styleName="myFontStyle"`
But when I ad `stylename=textArea` nothing is happening,

my css class

```
.textArea
{
    background-color:#000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}
```

Any tips ?

Comment: which flex sdk are you using 3.x or 4.x ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Flex 4 when you're using Spark theme you change the color of text area background with `contentBackgroundColor` not `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 1):

you can change background color of textarea with textArea skin class without using css.

```
<s:TextArea  skinClass="textAreaSkin" width="150" height="50"/>
```

First you create mxml skin class of textArea.

and just change background color of RichEditableText from that skin class.

```
<s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay" heightInLines="10" widthInChars="15" backgroundColor="red"/>
```